# Split String in Java with [a-z] regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have two regexpressions:

```
[a-c] : any character from a-c

[a-z] : any character from a-z
```

And a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcde";
    String[] arr1 = s.split("[a-c]");
    String[] arr2 = s.split("[a-z]");

    System.out.println(arr1.length); //prints 4 : "", "", "", "de"
    System.out.println(arr2.length); //prints 0 
}
```

Why the second splitting behaves like this? I would expect a reslut with 6 empty string "" results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the single-argument `String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

To keep the trailing strings, you can use the two-argument version, and specify a negative limit:

```
    String s = "abcde";
    String[] arr1 = s.split("[a-c]", -1); // ["", "", "", "de"]
    String[] arr2 = s.split("[a-z]", -1); // ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: i didn't noticed the trailing behavior described in the documentation, thanks

Answer (score 5):

By default, `split` discards trailing empty strings.  In the `arr2` case, they were all trailing empty strings, so they were all discarded.

To get 6 empty strings, pass a negative limit as the second parameter to the [`split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), which will keep all trailing empty strings.

```
String[] arr2 = s.split("[a-z]", -1);
```

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()`:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Around means that the matches themselves are removed. For example, splitting "a,b,c" on commas would be just `a` as well as `b` and `c`.

The first split removes the a, b, and c.

The second removes all letters, thus all characters from that string.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood the question: your answer is correct, but does not relate.

Comment: @ruakh "Why the second splitting behaves like this?" Editing now.